# Display Facebook ADs Statistics on webpage using Facebook Ads API in PHP

Tags: php, facebook, api, user-interface, facebook-graph-api

Does anyone know how to fetch all facebook ads statistics and display on webpage using **Facebook Ads Api-PHP SDK**. I am using this API and I am getting campaign details like name of campaign, id, status. but not able to get impressions,clicks, spent.

What I am doing let me share with you:
1) I am getting `access token` by authorizing user
2) After getting access token, I am using below code

```
$account = new AdAccount('act_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
$account->read();

$fields = array(
  AdCampaignFields::ID,
  AdCampaignFields::NAME,
  AdCampaignFields::OBJECTIVE,
);
$params = array(AdCampaignFields::STATUS => array(AdCampaign::STATUS_ACTIVE,AdCampaign::STATUS_PAUSED,),);
$campaigns = $account->getAdCampaigns($fields, $params);

/* Added By Jigar */     
$campaign = new AdCampaign('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
$compainDetails = $campaign->read($fields);
```

3) then printing the array

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($compainDetails); 
exit;
```

If anyone know any suggestion in above code, please share. All code is in PHP. Dose anyone have any tutorial that fetch all above required data then share it

Comment: Does anyone know how to fetch data using facebook ads api?

Comment: Does you app has access to this ad account? You may need to specify it from the App Settings page

Answer (score 2):

You could try to use the facebook insights api instead of $campaign->read. Here's an example:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights/v2.5#create-async-jobs

What you have to do to get impressions, click and spent is to add these fields to the $fields param. In your case, the complete code should look like the following:

```
    use FacebookAds\Object\Campaign;
    use FacebookAds\Object\Values\InsightsLevels;
    use FacebookAds\Object\Values\InsightsFields;

    $campaign = new Campaign();

    $fields = array(
      InsightsFields::IMPRESSIONS,
      InsightsFields::UNIQUE_CLICKS,
      InsightsFields::CALL_TO_ACTION_CLICKS,
      InsightsFields::INLINE_LINK_CLICKS,
      InsightsFields::SOCIAL_CLICKS,
      InsightsFields::UNIQUE_SOCIAL_CLICKS,
      InsightsFields::SPEND,
    );

    $params = array(
      'level' => InsightsLevels::CAMPAIGN,
    );

    $async_job = $campaign->getInsightsAsync($fields, $params);

    $async_job->read();
```

I don't know what exactly the "click" param means for you, but if you take a look at all these click params, I'm sure you'll find it or you'll know how to calculate it.
For a complete list of fields available on insights objects, have a look at: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-ads-sdk/blob/master/src/FacebookAds/Object/Fields/InsightsFields.php

Hope that helps.

Regards, Benjamin